# Rounding number when saving into CSV in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with columns composed of values in this way 413914995946952 (they were pasted as Value from another spreadsheet when they were calculated using a simple formula 41.3914995946952 * 100000000000000). However, when I save the spreadsheet into CSV and open it again, the values get rounded as this 413915000000000. How can I save the spreadsheet as CSV and keeping the original value? I'm using Excel (Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (version 2110 compilation 16.0.14527.20234) 64 bits)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  If I have `413914995946952` in some cell; save the worksheet as `.csv`, and then re-open in Excel, the same value is retained.  However, the cell itself has to also be **displaying** `413914995946952` (with or without commas).  In other words, formatted as a number.

Comment: The number is a float with a dot. I've tried to multiple and save the number using the same spreadsheet, however, the result is the same.

Comment: I thought you wrote that the number you were having trouble with was `413914995946952`.  How is that a float with a dot?  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will suite your purposes (though, can't see a reason why not): If you convert the values to text before saving as csv, the number will be preserved as is and, when you subsequently open the csv, it will be a number again. Conversation to text could be via =TEXT(A1,"000000000000000")